# My Heroku static site broke with the new PHP system

Tags: php, .htaccess, heroku, static-site

I have a static site running on Heroku. Up to now I have had an empty `index.php` alongside my `index.html`, and with `php_flag engine off` in `.htaccess`, everything ran smoothly. Heroku detected a PHP app but didn't run PHP for anything; `index.html` files took precedence.

Now with the switch to the new PHP system, I have been unable to get my static site working. It seems that the `php_flag engine off` is causing an Internal Server Error, but if I remove that then the server can't find `index.php`, so I get File Not Found. So I renamed all of my `index.html` files to `index.php`, but *then* the internal links in my site introduce a port for some reason (i.e. `example.com/foo` becomes `example.com:22481/foo`), so none of the links work.

What I'm trying to say is,

WHAT IS GOING ON PLEASE HELP

Comment: Can you provide a github repository to try and find out a solution for this?

Comment: My webpage is at http://www.hrothgar.me/. Currently the index files have extension `.html`, there is nothing in `.htaccess`, and `composer.json` exists but is empty.

For me, when I click on any of the links under the "Teaching" heading, I get unwanted port forwarding. Why does that happen?

Answer (score 1):

Try again; an update was released earlier that addresses this issue.

The new buildpack uses PHP via FastCGI; no need to set `engine off` anymore as there's no real overhead. The flag isn't supported anymore as it only works

Comment: I am still having an issue with port redirection. See my comment above on the OP — do you have any idea what is causing the direction?